# Dynamic page for downloading movie

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, download

I have made a movie downloadimg site [movihub4u.000webhostapp.com](http://movihub4u.000webhostapp.com) and now **I want to add a download page for it**.

I want to make a page which loads on clicking the movie image and the user gets redirected to new tab where there is movie image movie name and its download link. I want to make a single page which works for all movie I hope you got my question. *I don't know much about php so hope you may help*.

I have a similar code like :

```html
<img src="" />
<h1>heading to be shown</h1>
<a href="" >Download<a/>
```

I want to show heading, image and link in download button So how to make a page which changes everything on click image on different movie images.

Comment: Well you can implement that also in client side

Answer (score 0):

On your host page, you can use radio button OR you can set **ID**'s to all movies.
when a movie title is clicked , it will pass this *ID value* to the next page which in turn will show information on the basis of that value.
Hench you will need PHP.
Or you can use a technology like ASP.NET provided you know the technology well.

Comment: Akshata L I don't knoe about php can you tell what to write in code to do so

Comment: Assuming youre using radiobutton - name="name" and method=GET . PHP code will be:  <?php

if(isset($_GET["name"]))
{
$nameofmovie=$_GET["name"];
if($nameofmovie=="Inception")
 { echo" Inception<br> Link is:<a href="dummy.xyz"></a><img src="abc.png "/>";

 }
if($nameofmovie=="Salt")
 { echo" Salt<br> Link is:<a href="dummy.xyz"></a><img src="abc.png "/>";

 }
}

?>

Comment: This is an example where ive placed two movies. you can follow the structure and add others.Hope this helps.

Comment: Akshata L that is so much long I have 8 movie presently so i have to write if statement 8 times that's too long